# Can't insert timestamp into org file in Emacs

Tags: emacs, timestamp, org-mode

I am new to Emacs and Org mode. I am using Emacs for Mac version 27.1-1 on Mac OS Version 11.2 Beta.

When I try to insert a timestamp using `C-c .` or `M-x time-stamp`, Emacs shows error message `Invalid version syntax: '' (must start with a number)` in the echo area.

How can I debug this, to be able to insert a timestamp?

Comment: I am encountering the same issue. It appeared after I updated my emacs and restarted emacs. I keep all my emacs config in git. I revert any changes and it is still happening... seems something may have been silently updated and contains a bug.

Comment: I was able to resolve on my end by deleting all contents of my package repository in  `.emacs.d/elpa` I also believe my issue started after I installed the `org-drill` and completely removed that package. This is not a appropriate answer for the question but hopefully it helps.

Comment: I am encountering this issue also.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here: Updating from org 9.3.1 to 9.4.4 (Emacs 26.3 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) and suddenly `C-c .` and its derivatives `C-u C-c .`, `C-c !`, and `C-u C-c !` returns the `Invalid version syntax: '' (must start with a number)`.

The keys are still correctly bound though: `C-h f org-time-stamp` tells me so.

Inspired by kevzettler's answer I moved the new install out of my dot-emacs elpa dir and this resolved the issue, at the price of being back to version 9.3.1: `~/.emacs.d/elpa$ mv org-9.4.4/ ../.` So, something in org 9.4.4 causes this.

Solution: update to version `9.4.4-8-g33de2b-elpa` --- listed as `20210111` in Emacs package manager.